# How to extract the iOS specific code from chromium-iOS repo and only work in Xcode without ninja tool?

Tags: ios, xcode, chromium

I have downloaded and built the chromium from google repo but now I need to upload the code to git and the total size is too large to upload to git ( approx 20GB )

So, the question is that, is there any way to extract ios specific code and make a separate project in Xcode and manage that?

Comment: Chromium shares code with different platforms, so it's not worth it

Comment: @Asesh you mean it's not possible to extract the iOS-specific code, by saying "it's not worth it", right? or it is possible but requires enough knowledge and spare time to do it!

Comment: I meant the latter one, so it's not worth it.